# VM Workstation Suspend on Physical Host Stating To Shutdown

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

How i can make sure that when my physical machine shuts down it will suspend the VM Workstation machine. Basically my UPS is giving few minutes backup and then turns my Physical off when critical battery level is reach.

Where as some times i am not on seat and all open Workstation machines works get lost because they are not suspended by turned of during battery failure sundown. I need that when my physical machine is being showdown the running machines becomes suspended that showdown.

I saw a post with the same function be applied using SM Hyper-V but i am using VM WorkStation 15.5.5